# Jquery won't affect element/class in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to update the CSS of our site via Jquery based on which user is logging in. I need to hide an element (#BCID) and a class (.BC). Both are located in table.

When I manually enter the CSS ("display:hide") everything looks perfect. When I attempt to do it with Jquery (.css), nothing happens. I have tested other CSS commands on other elements with this same script and they work fine (adding borders, changing font color, etc.). But any attempt to change these elements utterly fails.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("document").ready(function() {
    var department = 'adam';
      $("#BCID").hide();
    if (department.toLowerCase() === "adam") {
      $('#BCID').css('border', '1opx solid black'); 
    }
    else {
      $("#SFID").css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using `===` to evaluate `department`?

Comment: It was what brackets suggested. I tried it with == as well.

Comment: You wrote "opx" instead "px" :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working ok here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7j6rys9/1/) but you have an error in your syntax (1opx solid black) which might be throwing it out:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var department = 'adam';
    $("#BCID").hide();
    if (department.toLowerCase() === "adam") {
      $('#BCID').css('border', '1px solid black'); 
    } else {
      $("#SFID").css('display', 'none');
    }
  });
```

Comment: nice catch! that's one of those hard to spot errors.

Comment: Fixed the error, but it still isn't working.

I modified the HTML to reflect what I have, namely, a table: 

<table>
<tr id="BCID">
  BCID
  </tr>
<tr id="SFID">
  SFID
</tr>
</table>

It stops working in the fiddle then.

Comment: You have errors in your markup, you cannot have a ````<tr>```` without a ````<td>```` as a child, I have updated the fiddle to show it working.